# Addition property for GCD

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I already know that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b). However, can I also say that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a+b,b)? I think this is correct and the proof is simple: consider gcd(a+b,b). Then apply this subtraction property of GCD's to say gcd(a+b,b)=gcd(a+b-b,b)=gcd(a,b) as required.

Comment: Yes. $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a \pm kb, b)$ for any non-zero integer $k$ and $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, b \pm ja)$ for any non-zero integer $j$.  But *don't* make the mistake of skipping a step and assuming $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a +kb, ja + b)$.   That isn't true.